# How to use regexp in routes with parameters?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

How to use regexp in routes with parameters?

I want to set reg exp for asset parametr.

For routes like this - `/opinions/a11`

```
@Get([
      '/:category(opinions)/:asset([a-z0-9]{1,7})'
  ])
```

PS:
It works, but how to limit length.
`/:category(opinions)/:asset([a-z0-9]+)`

Answer (score -1):

```
'/:category(opinions)/:asset([a-z0-9]{1\,3})'
```

Comment: Please, describe your answer: what is going on here and how can it solve the problem. Currently this regex is not valid

Comment: @astentx it works for routes like this - `/opinions/d12`

Comment: Backslash in front of comma shouldn't be here

Comment: shielding in reg exp